# How to use SQL function CONCAT with LIKE

Tags: sql, sql-server, concatenation

I confirmed that the columns in the SQL table contain the results I'm searching for (the results being NA), but when I use the query below, no results are returned.
Could I get some help with this please?

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM [DB_NAME].[dbo].[TABLE_NAME]
WHERE BECDescription like '%Time Warner%' AND
      (CONCAT(PhysicalAddress1, PhysicalCity, PhysicalStateProvince) like ('%NA%  %NA% %NA%')
      ) AND
      PhysicalCountry like '%NA%' AND
      CarrierName like '%NA%' AND
      CurrNetChargeAmt = 1326.00
```

Comment: Please include some sample data for the `MSAudit` table which explains what you are trying to do here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You concat PhysicalAddress1, PhysicalCity, PhysicalStateProvince but you add spaces between the '%NA'.

Try

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM [db_name].[dbo].[table_name]
WHERE BECDescription like '%Time Warner%' AND (CONCAT(PhysicalAddress1, ' ', PhysicalCity, ' ', PhysicalStateProvince) like ('%NA% %NA% %NA%')) AND PhysicalCountry like '%NA%' AND CarrierName like '%NA%' AND CurrNetChargeAmt = 1326.00
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and the quick response.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little lost on why you are using `CONCAT()` here.  Doesn't this do what you want?

```
WHERE BECDescription like '%Time Warner%' AND
      PhysicalAddress1 like '%NA%' AND
      PhysicalCity like '%NA%' AND
      PhysicalStateProvince like '%NA%' AND
      PhysicalCountry like '%NA%' AND
      CarrierName like '%NA%' AND
      CurrNetChargeAmt = 1326.00
```

It is certainly simpler to understand.